# pq driver: prepared statement does not exist

Tags: postgresql, go, prepared-statement, pgbouncer

I'm trying to connect to a postresql database with the [pq driver](https://github.com/lib/pq) in Go. When I do it on a local copy of the database, with a connection string like

```
DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=user password=pwd dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")
```

it all works well.

However, when I switch to a production server where the connection goes through pgbouncer:

```
DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=user password=pwd host=/var/run/pgbouncer port=port dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")
```

I keep getting the same error for all queries, however simple:

```
Database error: pq: S:"ERROR" M:"prepared statement \"1\" does not exist" C:"26000" F:"prepare.c" L:"519" R:"FetchPreparedStatement"
```

(it's always "prepared statement \"1\"", independent of the query I'm trying to pass)

The query in both cases is run simply as follows:

```
res_rows, err := DB.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Database error: %s\n", err)
}
for res_rows.Next() {
    ...
}
```

Googling suggests to turn off prepared statements, but I don't know how to do that in Go and I'm not sure it is supported at all. Any help (even a suggestion to use something else entirely) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are asking us to guess how you ran the queries which generated the errors. What Query and related methods, for example, Prepare methods, did you execute to cause the error.

Comment: Sorry, updated the post. I didn't use Prepare at all, just plain DB.Query right after sql.Open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Package driver](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/)
>
> [`type Queryer`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Queryer)
>
> ```
> type Queryer interface {
>     Query(query string, args []Value) (Rows, error)
> }
> ```
>
> `Queryer` is an optional interface that may be implemented by a
>   `Conn`.
>
> If a `Conn` does not implement `Queryer`, the `sql` package's
>   `DB.Query` will first prepare a query, execute the statement, and then
>   close the statement.

I don't see where the [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) PostgreSQL driver implements `Queryer`. Therefore, the `DB.Query` query is prepared before execution.

[PgBouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer) doesn't support the PREPARE feature for all pooling methods: [Feature matrix for pooling modes](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer#Feature_matrix_for_pooling_modes).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So basically this means that I cannot use Go in this setup?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using PgBouncer you need to set `binary_parameters=yes` to your database dsn connection as a query parameter

try this:
`DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=user password=pwd dbname=mydb sslmode=disable, binary_parameters=yes")`

Answer (score 4):

The Postgres driver now has a solution to fix this issue: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/389

It isn't in the documentation but works as expected, including with PgBouncer and Transaction pooling enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 it now supports protocol level named prepared statements, which would almost certainly resolve this error. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value in PgBouncer its config file. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements